# SubmitChanges to database is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following:

```
    var db = new datesDataContext();
    var query =
    from ord in db.Dates
    where ord.id == id
    select ord;

    foreach (Date ord in query)
    {
        ord.date1 = product.date1;
        ord.name = product.name;
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

It all runs fine (no errors, etc) except that SubmitChanges is not making the changes in the database.

ord.dat1 and ord.name are definitely being set...

edit: here's my date class (it says partial but it's the entire class, no other definition elsewhere):

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Dates")]
public partial class Date
{

    private System.Nullable<int> _id;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _date1 = DateTime.Now;

    private string _name;

    public Date()
    {
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_id", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._id != value))
            {
                this._id = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="date", Storage="_date1", DbType="DateTime")]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> date1
    {
        get
        {
            return this._date1;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._date1 != value))
            {
                this._date1 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_name", DbType="Text", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._name;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._name != value))
            {
                this._name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined primary key for Dates table in database?

Comment: @Jani nope... is that bad? (just been mucking around right now) the 'id' key should be the primary one but it's not defined as primary and can be nulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Date class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

EDIT:  implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your Date class

```
public partial class Date : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

         private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
         {
             if (PropertyChanged != null)
             {
                 PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
```

.....rest of class definition

and in each setter method use this code after changing values

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyName");
```

PropertyName in your case is id, date1 and name.

You also need to specify Primary Key otherwise tracking changes will not work.

Comment: thats the point. if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged then DataContext will be able to update the changes. see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Something must be wrong with either your configuration or your model classes.  Can you include code from the Date class as well?

I'm seeing this next to your "name" property: UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never

I'm guessing this setting is causing that property to not update.